# Enhancing video quality in Blackberry Application

Tags: blackberry

I am facing a problem in enhancing quality of the video feed that i recieve from the camera. For live video feed I am doing something like this

```
Player player= Manager.createPlayer("capture://video?encoding=jpeg&width=1280&height=1024&quality=normal");
```

Is there any way to improve video quality in this case and what options are available for 'quality' parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `CameraDemo` app from the BB SDK (should be present on yout dev PC).

It has a part that extracts/iterates all available for a device encoding properties:

```
String encodingString = System.getProperty("video.snapshot.encodings");
... the rest of the code
```

For instance, I noticed it is possible to request superfine quality: `.. &quality=superfine`